# Conditional template(html) loading with dojo AMD

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

So I have this simple require:

```
require(['app/'+url,'dojo/text!content/'+url], function(module,template){
        if(module.init){
                module.init({
                        container: panel, 
                        containerId: 'contentTabs_' + idOp,
                        template: template
                });
        }
});
```

But the template might not be there (sometimes it does). So whatever happens I'd like my require callback to be executed.

What is the AMD way to do this?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `dojo/text!`, write your own plugin:

```
require(['foo/maybe!'+url], function(maybeTemplate) {
  if (maybeTemplate === undefined) {
    // it's there
  } else {
    // it's not there
  }
}
```

`foo/maybe` must resolve to an object with a `load : function (id, require, callback)` member.

> ```
> load(
>   id,        // the string to the right of the !
>   require,   // AMD require; usually a context-sensitive require bound to the module making the plugin request
>   callback   // the function the plugin should call with the return value once it is done
> ) -> undefined
> ```

You can use an XHR call to fetch the resource and resolve to `undefined` on a 404 error.

- [Plugin documentation in the livedocs](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#plugins)
- [Dojo plugin example on my blog](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/dojo-adding-your-own-loader-plugins.html)

Comment: Good answer I came to the same conclusion. By the way, Does require return a Deffered?

Comment: `require` returns `undefined` - see [here](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd#the-amd-api). Bear in mind that the top-level API needs to retain compatibility with every other JS API that implements AMD. If you need to use a `Deferred` with `require`, create your own and resolve it in the callback function.